# Entity can't pass short (int16) values out

Tags: c#, entity

This is really holding up the process. 
I have a db of marks stored as short, and want to extract a single entry out and create summary statistics on it. It seems simple but I seem to have to jump through a ton of hoops to get it so must be missing something basic.

Here is the basic method, and this works happily. however all i can do with it is pass it to the DataGridView.

```
    private void MarksSummary(string StudentID)
        {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentID);
        //get the average of the marks using entity
        using (var context = new collegestudentsEntities1())
        {
            var StudentMarks = (from m in context.Marks
                                where m.StudIDFK == ID
                                select new
                                {
                                    m.Marks1,
                                    m.marks2,
                                    m.Marks3,
                                    m.Marks4
                                });
   dataGridView1.DataSource = StudentMarks.ToList();
```

Anything else, seems to be ridiculously long winded.

Eg: I can't do this

```
  var Marklist = new List<Int16>();
  StudentMarks.ToList().ForEach(m => Marklist.Add(m));
```

as I get "cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'short'"

or this

```
   Marklist = StudentMarks.ToList();
```

or this

```
 double av = Marklist.Average();
```

Yet I can do a forEach which is silly on one row of data

```
     foreach (var s in StudentMarks)
                {
                    Marklist.Add(s.Marks1);
                   Marklist.Add(s.marks2);
                    Marklist.Add(s.Marks3);
                    Marklist.Add(s.Marks4);
                }
```

and this works outputting happily

```
            txtMarksOverFifty.Text = Marklist.Count(s => s > 50).ToString();
            txtMarksFailed.Text = Marklist.Count(s => s < 50).ToString();
```

So what am I missing to get the values out of the query easily?

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `foreach` is trying to add an anonymous type

```
select new
{
    m.Marks1,
    m.marks2,
    m.Marks3,
    m.Marks4
} //...
```

To a `List<Int16>` so it's not surprising that fails. What it looks like you want to do with that is:

```
StudentMarks.ToList().ForEach(m => Marklist.AddRange(new [] { m.Marks1, m.marks2, m.Marks3, m.Marks4 }));
```

Edit: If you're just looking for a solution with less code you might try:

```
using (var context = new collegestudentsEntities1())
{
    var StudentMarks = (from m in context.Marks
                        where m.StudIDFK == ID
                        select new[]
                        {
                            m.Marks1,
                            m.marks2,
                            m.Marks3,
                            m.Marks4
                        }).SelectMany(mark => mark).ToList();
}
```

or simply:

```
    List<Int16> Marklist = context.Marks.Where(mark => mark.StudIDFK == ID)
        .SelectMany(m => new [] { m.Marks1, m.marks2, m.Marks3, m.Marks4 })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the model maps an int16 to a db smallint and calls it a short. So if I made a list<int16> shouldn't they easily pass across? can't I just go var Marklist = new List<Int16>(); and then Marklist = StudentMarks.ToList(); ?

Comment: No, because each object within `StudentMarks` isn't an `Int16`, it's an Object that contains some `Int16` properties.

Comment: @netchicken I've updated my solution with some other options that should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you are creating here:

```
select new
{
   m.Marks1,
   m.marks2,
   m.Marks3,
   m.Marks4
});
```

This is an object that contains shorts.

```
StudentMarks.ToList().ForEach(m => Marklist.Add(m));
```

Here you are trying to add an object to a list of shorts.  Try:

```
StudentMarks.ToList().ForEach(m => {
Marklist.Add(m.Mark1);
Marklist.Add(m.Mark2);
Marklist.Add(m.Mark3);
Marklist.Add(m.Mark4);
```

}
);